# fixed scaling in opengl

Tags: opengl, scaling

can anyone help me out in scaling of opengl.
i am using the glScalef() function to scale polygons but what i want is that the scaling is done on a fixed point but it is not achieved with the following function.
can some one put some light on this?

Comment: You need to be more specific about your particular problem. May be illustrate it with an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scaling generally happens around the origin. Therefore, to scale around a point (x,y,z), one must translate the origin, and back.

Specifically:

- translate by (-x, -y, -z)
- scale
- translate by (x, y, z)

Note: it is the very same thing as rotating around a point.